# Reference request for sums of Grothendieck spaces

Tags: reference-request, banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

I much appreciate your help with my previous question. Now, I'd like to ask about a reference. I need a fact asserting that if $p\in (1,\infty]$ (with emphasis on the case $p=\infty$) then the $\ell_p$-sum of an arbitrary (possibly uncountable) family of Grothendieck spaces is Grothendieck.

Best wishes,
A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $1< p<\infty$ it is an exercise (which, in fact, some of my students did this past semester).

For $p=\infty$ it is false. The space $(\ell_1^1\oplus \ell_1^2 \oplus \ell_1^3 \oplus \dots)_\infty$ contains a norm one complemented subspace that is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_1$ (another exercise for my students this past term), and being a Grothendieck space passes to complemented subspaces.

Comment: For $p\in (1,\infty)$ the proof (of this exercise) can be found in http://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-18-3/18J3Plich.pdf (Lemma 1).